# After setting a EditText to be unclickable, it still responds to Click events

Tags: android

I'm making an App for Android.
I have an EditText, which in the XML layout I have it set not to be focusable but clickable.

I have a Click listener event on the EditText, so if a user tries to add something to the EditText, it gives the user a warning telling them that they first need to do something else.

After they do that something else, I have my code sets the EditText's Focusable in TouchMode to true, and clickable to false.

The Focusable part is working, but whenever I touch the EditText it's still responding to the `onClickListener()`.

Any idea why setting clickable to false isn't disabling the EditText's ability to respond to click events?

Comment: set the setOnClickListener(null) after "something else" is complete

Comment: Usually .setClcikable(false); will disable all click events, but other commands e.g. .setFocusable(...) will enable the clickable again. Are you first setting the clickable to false and after it enabling the focusable or do something else, which enables the clickable again?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
myEditText.setOnClickListener(null);
```

And then when the user is filled the spaces that you need to be filled, you set the listener to something:

```
myEditText.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

or:

```
myEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now I have onClickListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

And this is it. Hope this helps.